# How to make OCI8 uses 9iR2client libraries on Linux?

Tags: php, oracle, ubuntu, oci8, oracle8i

I need to connect to an Oracle 8i server, but oci8 does not support it by default.

The php documentation says as following:

**Note**:

> If `OCI8` uses `9iR2` client libraries, then `PHP` can connect to Oracle Database `8i`, `9iR2`, `10g` or `11g`. If `OCI8` uses `10gR2` client libraries, the database can be `9iR2`, `10g`, `11g` or `12c`. If `OCI8` uses `11g` client libraries, the database can be `9iR2`, `10g`, `11g` or `12c`. If `OCI8` uses `12c` client libraries, the database can be `10gR2`, `11g` or `12c`.

How can I setup `OCI8` to use `9iR2` client libraries?

My current environment is:

I'm on a **ubuntu** server,
`Oracle 8i` version 8.1.7.4.0
I have already installed instantclient libraries(I'm able to connect to oracle 10i and above)
I'm using instantclient version 12.1... Also tried with instantclient version 10.2

Could someone help me figuring out what the problem might be and how to solve it? Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Exactly what version of "8i" are you trying to connect to?  The requirements for 8.1.5, for example, are rather different than the requirements for 8.1.7.4.  Oracle doesn't generally make obsolete versions of products available for download so you can't download the 9.2 client libraries any longer.  If you have a support contract, you can log a Metalink support request and Oracle support can get you the old libraries.  Of course, those old libraries may require a rather old version of linux.

Comment: @JustinCave the version is 8.1.7.4.0. I'm updating my question.
I will try to find a way to download 9.2 client libraries. This is the instantclient libraries, correct?
Thanks so much for the answer. I really appreciate

Comment: I'm not sure that the Instant Client existed back in the Oracle 9.2 days.  My guess is that you'd need the full Oracle client install which is a few hundred MB.  If you've got a support contract, Oracle Support can send you obsolete software on CD.  It's reasonably likely, though, that the Oracle 9.2 client won't be compatible with whatever version of linux you have and that you'd have to downgrade to an older version.